# C# WPF Telerik RadCartesianChart: force a constant length of the axes despite the presence of labels

Tags: wpf, charts, telerik

I have created a very simple chart like this:

```
<telerik:RadCartesianChart x:Name="chartMainCandleChart" Height="350" Width="620" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ZoomChanged="chartMainCandleChart_ZoomChanged" PanOffsetChanged="chartMainCandleChart_OffsetChanged" >
    <telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
        <telerik:DateTimeCategoricalAxis SmartLabelsMode="SmartStep" IsStepRecalculationOnZoomEnabled="False" />
    </telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
    <telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
        <telerik:LinearAxis HorizontalLocation="Right" SmartLabelsMode="SmartStep" IsStepRecalculationOnZoomEnabled="False"/>
    </telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
    <telerik:CandlestickSeries x:Name="candleSeries" ItemsSource="{Binding SeriesCollection}" CategoryBinding="Timestamp" OpenBinding="Open" CloseBinding="Close" LowBinding="Low" HighBinding="High">
        <telerik:CandlestickSeries.DefaultVisualStyle>
            <Style TargetType="telerik:Candlestick">
                <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2" />
                <Setter Property="UpStroke" Value="GreenYellow"/>
                <Setter Property="DownStroke" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="UpFill" Value="GreenYellow"/>
                <Setter Property="DownFill" Value="Red"/>
            </Style>
        </telerik:CandlestickSeries.DefaultVisualStyle>
    </telerik:CandlestickSeries>

    <telerik:RadCartesianChart.Behaviors>
        <telerik:ChartPanAndZoomBehavior x:Name="bvPanZoom" MouseWheelMode="ZoomHorizontally" DragMode="Pan" PanMode="Horizontal" ZoomMode="None" />
    </telerik:RadCartesianChart.Behaviors>

    <telerik:RadCartesianChart.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="telerik:PanZoomBar">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Style>
    </telerik:RadCartesianChart.Resources>
</telerik:RadCartesianChart>
```

I autoscale it using this function during OffsetChanged Event:

```
private void ScaleChartDynamically()
{
    var viewPortWidth = chartMainCandleChart.PlotAreaClip.Width;
    var xPixelsPerElem = viewPortWidth * chartMainCandleChart.Zoom.Width / SeriesCollection.Count;
    var notVisible = -chartMainCandleChart.PanOffset.X / xPixelsPerElem; // how many candles are invisible completely (on the left of viewport)
    var visible = viewPortWidth / xPixelsPerElem; // last partially visible in viewport
    var firstElem = (int)Math.Floor(notVisible) + 1; // index is zero based
    var lastElem = (int)Math.Ceiling(notVisible + visible);
    var noElements = lastElem - firstElem + 1;

    var visibleRange = SeriesCollection.Range(firstElem, noElements).SelectMany(ohlc => new[] { ohlc.Low, ohlc.High }).Select(hl => hl.ToDouble()).ToArray();
    if (visibleRange.Any())
    {
        var yAxis = (LinearAxis)chartMainCandleChart.VerticalAxis;
        yAxis.Minimum = visibleRange.Min();
        yAxis.Maximum = visibleRange.Max();
    }
}
```

I experience the following problem when dragging along x-axis:

[image: chart bug]

It looks like the problem has been addressed here:
https://www.telerik.com/forums/fixed-width-height-for-axis
but the provided solution doesn't solve the issue at all.

I am temporarily using workaround that takes PlotAreaClip.Width once, on LeftMouseButtonClick to prevent "jumping" while dragging:

```
private double _plotAreaClipWidth;

private void chartMainCandleChart_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    _plotAreaClipWidth = chartMainCandleChart.PlotAreaClip.Width;
}
```

The first line of ScaleChartDynamically() function is now:

```
var viewPortWidth = _plotAreaClipWidth;
```

So to clarify:

I want to remove the gap visible in the picture below, the gap is changing which causes chart to "jump" (rise an event again) whenever PlotAreaClip.Width is different. In other words I want to force the size of PlotAreaClip.Width (length of x-axis) and keep the labels, they should be cut off on both ends of the axis. To meet my general requirements, PlotAreaClip with axes should span across entire control rendering area without artificial gaps for labels. Bounty goes to the person that shows me how to do that. You can see what I mean by looking at the example below. See how length of x-axis is changing when zooming/dragging to accomodate the labels. This is the cause of the problem that resizes PlotAreaClip.Width and creates blank space on the sides of the chart. If you look closely you can see that the same issue can be visible on y-axis as well:

[image: gap]

[image: zoom x-axis resize]

Comment: @rvnload Could you also provide code for SeriesCollection Property

Comment: Assume it is just: "ObservableCollection<OHLC> SeriesCollection { get; set; }" where OHLC signature looks like this: OHLC(decimal open, decimal high, decimal low, decimal close). It doesn't matter though because as you can see I understand the cause of initial problem now, I just want to know how to tweak telerik chart to keep axes length constant.

Comment: Please don't feel i am asking every time the code, but to reproduce to issue on my side, i need s PlotAreaClip.Width on LeftMouseButtonClick code.-:)

Comment: I added clarifications, if you need anything else, just ask. I am not upset I am actually glad because you are the only person who is trying to help.